# What is operator ? When is an operator called linear operator?

Tags: linear-algebra

While having integrator and diffrentior,We exchange both of them saying that they are linear. I want clear picture of those types of linear operators

Comment: The term "operator" can have different meaning in different contexts...

Comment: See [Operator (mathematics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_(mathematics)).

Answer (score 3):

An operator $f:S \to S$ is linear whenever $S$ has addition and scalar multiplication, when:

- $f(a+b) = f(a)+f(b)$
- $f(kx) = kf(x)$

where $k$ is a scalar.

Answer (score 1):

when the domain and co-domain are same we say that function is an operator.If function is linear,we say it is linear operator

Comment: "when the domain and co-domain are same we say that function is an operator" ??? Is this your private definition ?

Comment: @Fred  I didn't try to give a proper definition.But this is what i have learned in linear algebra .Please enlighten me by giving the correct one.